# Javamail IMAP OAUTH2/SASL Exception

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail, imap, sasl

I am currently working on a IMAP Messenger, I am trying to get the users google username and authorization token from the built in account manager, and keep getting errors based around SASL as my store tries to connect.

Here is my current code:

```
private class logIn extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){
        // Get Username && Auth Token
        AccountManager accountManager=AccountManager.get(getActivity());
        Account[] accounts=accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        if(accounts[0].name.toLowerCase().endsWith("gmail.com")){
            username=accounts[0].name.toLowerCase();
            System.out.println(username);
            accountManager.getAuthToken(accounts[0],"oauth2:https://mail.google.com/",null,getActivity(),new onPasswordAcquired(),null);
        }
        // Start Store Session
        if(password!=null){
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.imap.sasl.enable","true");
            props.put("mail.imap.sasl.mechanisms","XOAUTH2");
            props.put("mail.imap.auth.login.disable","true");
            props.put("mail.imap.auth.plain.disable","true");
            try{
                Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(props,new Gmail_Authenticator(username,password));
                session.setDebug(true);
                store=session.getStore("imap");
                store.connect("imap.gmail.com",username,password);
            }catch(MessagingException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            if(store!=null && store.isConnected()){loadmsg=true;}
        }
        return "Executed";
    }
```

Here is the Error I am getting:

```
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.wq.myapp, PID: 10711
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/security/sasl/Sasl;
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator.authenticate(IMAPSaslAuthenticator.java:143)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.sasllogin(IMAPProtocol.java:846)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:805)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:703)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wq.myapp.GmailMessagesFrag$logIn.doInBackground(GmailMessagesFrag.java:418)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wq.myapp.GmailMessagesFrag$logIn.doInBackground(GmailMessagesFrag.java:394)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.security.sasl.Sasl" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.wq.myapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPSaslAuthenticator.authenticate(IMAPSaslAuthenticator.java:143) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.sasllogin(IMAPProtocol.java:846) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.login(IMAPStore.java:805) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:703) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:364) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wq.myapp.GmailMessagesFrag$logIn.doInBackground(GmailMessagesFrag.java:418) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.wq.myapp.GmailMessagesFrag$logIn.doInBackground(GmailMessagesFrag.java:394) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:   Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.security.sasl.Sasl
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:           ... 15 more
12-16 18:56:22.836 10711-11216/com.example.wq.myapp E/AndroidRuntime:  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

I have tried adding some libraries that included "javax.security" classes and get an error saying:

```
ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
...
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been struggling on this for a week now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [JavaMail for Android](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Android) docs:

> One of the standard Java features not supported on Android is SASL.
>   This latest version of JavaMail includes built-in OAuth2 support that doesn't require SASL.

Here is the example from the [OAuth2 Support](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/OAuth2) documentation to enable it:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true"); // required for Gmail
props.put("mail.imap.auth.mechanisms", "XOAUTH2");
Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
Store store = session.getStore("imap");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", username, oauth2_access_token);
```

Comment: I was using javamail 1.5.4, Thankyou so much!! That worked perfectly!! :) :)